# Can you create a voicemail to leave automatically if the call isn't answered, Flex => Customer

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

Quick Question:

I am attempting to implement an automatic voicemail feature in my Twilio Flex application, where if a customer does not answer a call made by an agent, the system will automatically leave a voicemail message. I know that it is possible to implement the opposite scenario, where the customer can leave a voicemail for the agent, but I am not sure if it is possible to implement the automatic voicemail feature in the way that I described. Can someone with expertise in Twilio Flex provide guidance on how to achieve this functionality?

Thank you in advance for your help.